# Is there a way to create a dataframe in python from start date to end date

Tags: python, pandas

Is there way to create a dataframe(using pandas) from start date to End date with random values

For example, the required data frame:

```
date          value 
2015-06-25     12
2015-06-26     23
2015-06-27     3.4
2015-06-28     5.6
```

Is this dataframe I need to set "from date" to "To date" so that there is no need to type manually because the rows keep on increasing and "value" column should have values generated randomly

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see [pandas.date_range](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html).

Comment: hi @navee pp. Is your question solved? Please consider accepting an answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) and [`numpy.random.uniform`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html):

```
import numpy as np
dates = pd.date_range('2015-06-25', '2015-06-28', freq='D')

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': dates,
                   'value': np.random.uniform(0, 50, size=len(dates))})
```

output:

```
        date      value
0 2015-06-25  39.496971
1 2015-06-26  29.947877
2 2015-06-27   7.328549
3 2015-06-28   6.738427
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
beg = '2015-06-25 '
end = '2015-06-28'
index = pd.date_range(beg, end)
values = np.random.rand(len(index))
df = pd.DataFrame(values, index=index)
```

| index | 0 |
| --- | --- |
| 2015-06-25 00:00:00 | 0.865455754057059 |
| 2015-06-26 00:00:00 | 0.959574113247196 |
| 2015-06-27 00:00:00 | 0.8634928651970131 |
| 2015-06-28 00:00:00 | 0.6448579391510935 |